Flutter: How to Make PageView Work in Bottom Sheet Without Fixed Height?
I'm implementing smooth slide-in and slide-out effects for authentication widgets in my Flutter application. To achieve this, I've placed them within a PageView, as demonstrated in the code snippet below.
However, I've encountered a problem: When the PageView is contained within a bottom sheet, the app crashes and fails to render it because the PageView requires a fixed height to function properly.
I'm seeking a workaround that allows the PageView to render and function correctly without requiring a fixed height. I want it to dynamically adjust its height to fit its content.
_openAuthenticationSheet() async {
  PageController pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
        topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
      ),
    ),
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setState) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                _buildAuthenticationHeaderIcons(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .69, // I don't want this.
                  child: PageView(
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: pageController,
                    children: [
                      LogInScreen(
                        key: const ValueKey("login"),
                        navBarColor: navbarColor,
                        handleSignUp: () {
                          pageController.animateToPage(1,
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                              curve: Curves.easeInOut);
                        },
                      ),
                      SignUpScreen(
                        key: const ValueKey("sign_up"),
                        navBarColor: navbarColor,
                        handleLogIn: () {
                          pageController.animateToPage(0,
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                              curve: Curves.easeInOut);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  )
}

Thanks in anticipations on any ideas/suggestions.

Try below code hope its help to you.
Declartion:
 PageController controller = PageController();

Widget:
ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: PageView(
                        controller: controller,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            color: Colors.pink,
                            child: Text(
                              'First Page',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 30,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            color: Colors.yellow,
                            child: Text(
                              'Second Page',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 30,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(
                              'Third Page',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 30,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.brown,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(
                              'Fourth Page',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 30,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(
                              'Fifth Page',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 30,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
        child: Text('Open bottom sheet'),
      ),

